# Visualising 2-step sequence data to spot the differences among two different user groups

Tags: python, visualization, pandas, ggplot2

I have the following data frame for a certain user group. Basically, it shows the current page, and the previous page visited across all users. For example, 81 users come from BLQ2_2 to visit BLQ2_1. I have the same data set for another user group. I am trying find an effective way of visualising these data sets to spot the differences among the user groups.

```
PAGE    PREV_PAGE COUNT  
BLQ2_1  BLQ2_2    81
        BLQ2_4     8
        BLQ2_3     6
        BLQ2_1     3
BLQ2_2  BLQ2_3    91
        BLQ2_4    22
        BLQ2_1     9
        BLQ2_5     5
        BLQ2_2     1
BLQ2_3  BLQ2_4    87
        BLQ2_1    12
        BLQ2_5     6
        BLQ2_2     2
        BLQ2_3     1
BLQ2_4  BLQ2_5    45
        BLQ2_1    26
        BLQ2_2    17
        BLQ2_3     8
        BLQ2_4     3
BLQ2_5  BLQ2_1    19
        BLQ2_2    12
        BLQ2_4    12
        BLQ2_5     8
        BLQ2_3     6
```

A bar chart could help. But, I wonder if there are other options around there that I could not think of. Another option could be arranging the pages like this:

```
BLQ2_1       BLQ2_2      BLQ2_3       BLQ2_4      BLQ2_5
```

and connecting them based on the visits (e.g., drawing a thick line -considering the COUNT value is 81- from BLQ2_2 to BLQ2_1)

I appreciate some input.